# When should we use Vue.js's component

Tags: web, vue.js

When I study the feature of Vue.js's component system. I feel confused when and where should we use this? In Vue.js's doc they said

> Vue.js allows you to treat extended Vue subclasses as reusable
>   components that are conceptually similar to Web Components, without
>   requiring any polyfills.

But based on their example it doesn't clear to me how does it help to reuse. I even think it complex the logic flow.

Comment: tl;dr cross-browser non-standard Web Components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, you use "alerts" a lot in your app. If you have experienced bootstrap, the alert would be like:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <strong>Title!</strong> Alert body ...
</div>
```

Instead of writing it over and over again, you can actually make it into a component in Vue:

```
Vue.component('alert', {
    props: ['type','bold','msg'],
    data : function() { return { isShown: true }; },
    methods : {
        closeAlert : function() {
            this.isShown = false;
        }
    }
});
```

And the HTML template (just to make it clear, I separate this from the Vue Comp above):

```
<div class="alert alert-{{ type }}" v-show="isShown">
    <button type="button" class="close" v-on="click: closeAlert()">&times;</button>
    <strong>{{ bold }}</strong> {{ msg }}
</div>
```

Then you can just call it like this:

```
<alert type="success|danger|warning|success" bold="Oops!" msg="This is the message"></alert>
```

Note that this is just a 4-lines of template code, imagine when your app uses lot of  "widgets" with 100++ lines of code

Hope this answers..